# How to harmonize husky pre-commit hook when working with pretty-quick in my node.js project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, git, prettier, husky

I have a husky pre-commit hook in my `package.json` file:

```json
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "npx pretty-quick --staged"
  }
}
```

I also have a `.prettierrc` file in my project:

```json
{
  "printWidth": 100,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

My problem is that when I change a file (which is already properly formatted) and run `npx pretty-quick --staged` I see what I expect:

```
  Finding changed files since git revision 88264bc2a.
  Found 1 changed file.
✅  Everything is awesome!
```

but when I try to do `git commit` the same command is run with the hook and I get this output:

```
husky > pre-commit (node v14.17.0)
  Finding changed files since git revision 88264bc2a.
  Found 1 changed file.
✍️  Fixing up src/somefile.ts.
✅  Everything is awesome!
```

It is not supposed to fix that file up since it was already properly formatted. I checked the configuration options of `pretty-quick` and there is no option to figure out which prettier config it is using and I also cannot tell it explicitly which one to use (although I only have one `.prettierrc` file).

What am I doing wrong? It seems that pretty-quick / husky doesn't pick up my `.prettierrc` and it uses some default config.